# Does CdiCenteroutput support in lipari-mid & kiska - mid (55ppm)

Tags: iot

Does CdiCenterOutput support in lipari-mid & kiska - mid (55ppm) when GB finisher attached?

enum CdiOffsetModes
{
cdiCenterOutput              = 0x04

Need to know Whether the lipari-mid & kiska - mid (55ppm) mechines support CdiCenterOutput or NOT?